# Using x.size() in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am rying to create a simple if statement that checks if a feature collection is empty, and if so regenerates it with random samples. Even though it's counting my FC size correctly, it will not evaluate 0 == 0 as true. I've tried coercing both the result of the .size() call and the 0 used to evaluate every way I can think of. I've tried converting to a list and using .length() instead. If I just set "fcSize = 0" it works fine.

What am I missing?

```
  var aFeatureCollection = aFunction();
  
  var fcSize = aFeatureCollection.size();
  
  print(fcSize); <- says it's 0
  
  if(fcSize === 0){
    
     doAThing();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fcSize` is a server-side object, so you cannot do a client-side equality check on it. Read [Client vs. Server](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server) in the Earth Engine docs.

```
var aFeatureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection([])
var fcSize = aFeatureCollection.size();
print('fcSize', fcSize)  
print('fcSize === 0', fcSize === 0)
print('fcSize.eq(0)', fcSize.eq(0))
print('fcSize.eq(5)', fcSize.eq(5))
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/a40de1bba71ba4307a186b6b55300be4